# DropDownListFor selected value is ok locally but not selected on deployed app

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have DropDownListFor in my View. I need to get selected value according to passed property in my viewModel.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.CharacterClass, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassEnum)).Cast<ClassEnum>(), Model.CharacterClass), new { @class = "form-design" })
```

When debugging locally everything works fine. All of my drop down lists are selected properly according to model. But when i deploy my app online. None of my drop down list is selected on model property value, even if i pass the same model data as with debugging.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the problem is a configuration mismatch between your dev and your prod environments.

Comment: Maybe, but i have no clue which one. I am changing nothing when publishing it.